# How to limit the content of my activity to not climb below the ActionBar when I'm using Translucent StatusBar?

Tags: android, statusbar

How to limit the content of my activity to not climb below the ActionBar when I'm using Translucent StatusBar? My content is below the ActionBar -.-"

Style (using in AppTheme):

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows" tools:ignore="NewApi">true</item>
```

[image]

---

Solved using this code after setContentView:

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams params
                    = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.setMargins(0, getStatusBarHeight() + getActionBarHeight(), 0, 0);
            drawer.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Methods:

```
public int getStatusBarHeight() {
        int result = 0;
        int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        if (resourceId > 0) {
            result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public int getActionBarHeight(){
        TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
        int actionBarHeight = 0;
        if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)){
            actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        return actionBarHeight;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the android:windowActionBarOverlay property in your style and set it to false. if this property is true the activity will be drawn so that it occupies the entire screen space and the action bar is drawn on top of the activity content.

Answer (score 0):

On your layout, set the property `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

For example:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"

      android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

This will make your content fits between the action bar and the navigation bar.
And you will avoid having to programatically set the margin.